# Trouble Accessing Ruby Array and Hash Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making an api call and receiving the following response (it's long, so I'm showing the important part):

```
... "fields":{"count"_1:["0"],"count_2":["5"]} ...
```

when I do:

```
call["fields"]["count_1"]
```

It returns

```
["0"]
```

I need it to give me just the integer. I tried:

```
call["fields"]["count_1"][0]
```

And I also tried:

```
call["fields"]["count_1"][0].to_i
```

I'm running this in Rails and it gives me the error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

But it's not working.

Comment: If it's returning `["0"]` as you claim, then adding `[0]` will work fine.

Comment: What should the result be?

Comment: @WayneConrad see what OP wrote **I need it to give me just the integer.** `call["fields"]["count_1"][0]` gives `"0"`. But he wanted `0`.

Comment: @Arup _0_ is a reasonable interpretation of "just give me the integer."  So is _48_ (the ASCII code for the character "0").

Comment: @user2270029 - Can you please add an executable subset of the response to the API call?  It should be something we can paste into irb and have it run.  This would greatly aid us in helping you fix the problem.  Also, when it doesn't work, please describe how it doesn't work.  Does it give you an error message?  Also, please add the exact result you expect.  Thanks!

Comment: Based on all these problems you are happening, can you copy/paste the result of ```puts call.inspect```? I think the data does not look like you have pasted, at this point.

Comment: @sethcall I have same opinion like you..

Comment: Is this response one big string?

Answer (score 2):

Try as below using [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i)

```
call["fields"]["count_1"][0].to_i # => 0
```

Comment: I tried that. Didn't work. Very strange. Seems like it would.

Comment: @user2270029 what result you want.. `0` or `"0"` ?

Comment: I want the result of just the integer, so 0

Comment: @user2270029 It should work.. check your data, if it is exactly same as you have given here.

Answer (score 2):

Some tips:

1. Try wrapping the API response in `JSON.parse(...)`. That is, if you're not making the call via a gem that already does this. This might `require 'json'`.
2. Try `call['fields']['count_1'].first.to_i`
3. Do some debugging: check the value of `call.class`, `call['fields'].class` and `call['fields']['count_1'].class`. The last one should definitly be an **Array**.
4. Add an `if` clause to check if `call['fields'][['count_1'].is_empty?`.
5. Look for typos :)

Comment: It's strange because this same code is working on another page. I've literally copied and pasted it to check it.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the API call was making the zeros nil instead of zero. Thanks for all your help.